# android load thumbnails for images in SD card

Tags: android, image, thumbnails

I use a gridview to display all the images in user's camera folder. I load all the images and build thumbnails by myself. After I did this, I saw that android allow to get directly the thumbnails. Here my issue starts: I didn't find a working example for this.

To summarize, my issue is this: I want to get all the thumbnails in my camera folder and to display them in a grid. To simplify, I want to build a list of thumbnails (as bitmap, or, preferable path to thumbnail image) and the full path to corresponding image.

Someone can help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for :)

Displaying images from SD card in Android: http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.in/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html

Another approach (more complex): http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.in/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html

One more example: http://androidsamples.blogspot.in/2009/06/how-to-display-thumbnails-of-images.html